# Multiple users with the same avatar in the chat?

Tags: bug, chat, profile-picture

I see in the chat after a while multiple users with the same avatar. I guess this must be a bug. Also after a refresh I got three same avatars which ended up on differnt SO profiles ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751054/chandan-kumar), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2845352/amar), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2846143/user2846143)) which had differnt avatars but not the shown.

[image: Multiple users with same avatar]

Maybe helpful here is the avatar:
[image]

Comment: Thats just cerberus, don't worry, he only bothers the dammed

Comment: @RichardTingle hm I see that you got 7 upvotes for that comment, but I don't get it. Maybe my english skills are to bad. Could you explain that?

Comment: It was a joke, cerberus is a 3 headed dog from Greek and Roman mythology. I'm afraid I don't know what causes this problem (I had hoped someone else would)

Comment: This seems to be the identicon when no hash is given, the "default" identicon, if you would. I have no idea what makes chat to not read the actual user's profile picture/identicon and use that one.